# How to combine bootstrap accordion and bootstrap tooltip on ipad?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-bootstrap, bootstrap-popover

The problem is next:
when I have a tooltip icon that should show a tooltip on ipad user has to click it when popover-trigger is "mouseenter". But it opens an accordion.

```
<uib-accordion close-others="true">
  <div uib-accordion-group  class="" ng-repeat="lesson in subject.lessons | orderBy:'order'
           track by $index" is-open="$first" >    
      <uib-accordion-heading>
         <h4>                                                                                                                       
            <span class="lesson-title">{{lesson.name}}</span>
               <i class="fa fa-question-circle"  popover-placement="left" 
                     popover-trigger="mouseenter"  uib-popover="{{lesson.tooltip}}">
               </i>
         </h4>
      </uib-accordion-heading>
<div>....
```

[image: UI sample]

Comment: Add click/touch handler to `<i>` and stop the event from propagating to the underlying header element.

Comment: @J.Titus you are simply genius. Thank you